# How to delete an app from a django project

Tags: python, django

Initially I made 2 apps (app_a and app_b) in a single project in Django. Now I want to delete one (say app_a). How should I do so? Is removing the app name from `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file sufficient?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to remove or check the following:

- Remove the app from `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Remove any database tables for the models in that app (see `app_name_model_name` in your database).
- Check for any imports in other apps (it could be that they're importing code from that app).
- Check templates if they are using any template tags of that app (which would produce errors if that app is no longer there).
- Check your settings file to see if you're not using any code from that app (such as a context processor in `your_app/context_processors.py`, if it has such as file).
- Check if any static content of the app is used in other apps.
- Remove the app directory entirely.

When you've been following proper coding principles (i.e., each Django app is a self-contained part of the web application) then most situations above won't occur. But when other apps do use some parts of that app, you need to check that first as it may require refactoring before deleting the app.

Comment: What's about django_contet_type, auth_permission and other auth tables (besides django_migration if required)?

Comment: This answer is complemented this other one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745220/how-to-remove-an-app-from-a-django-projects-and-all-its-tables (which mentions auth_permission and other tables)

Comment: Hi everyone. I think.. if it's a procedure, it should be done by django, provided in the same way you execute a subcommand to create one. Don't you think?

Comment: also check /settings/<project>/url.py

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the app (how it was installed, how it was used, etc) but usually you can remove app from `INSTALLED_APPS` and then delete its tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

if, after the operations explained by **Simeon Visser** and in the other answer referenced by **Elias Dorneles** in the comments, you get somthing like this after a runserver :

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\releases\381_x64\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
  [...]
  File "c:\python\env\django3python381\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration oeuvres.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('medias', '0001_initial')
```

browse to your appname.migrations folder and comment any references to the app you want to remove. In the case above, the **oeuvres** app had a dependency to the **medias** app, which I want to remove, defined in the **oeuvres.0001_initial** migration file.

I don't think/don't know yet if this will have consequences on the migration processes but I intend to reset all migrations stuff for production then import datas ie as described here :
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html